# thrift server excute cmd in java appear CancelledKeyException and epoll bug

Tags: java, thrift

thriftServer:  TThreadedSelectorServer

when i use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) or Apache DefaultExecutor to excute linux command 'ls -al xxxx', is always appears:

```
 WARN Thread-3 org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadedSelectorServer - Created new Selector.
 WARN Thread-3 org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadedSelectorServer - Replace new selector success.
 ERROR Thread-3 org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadedSelectorServer - run() on SelectorThread exiting due to uncaught error
 java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:82)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.changeSelectInterests(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:441)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$AbstractSelectThread.processInterestChanges(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:191)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadedSelectorServer$SelectorThread.run(TThreadedSelectorServer.java:548)
```

client code

```
public static void test()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (;;)
        {
            try (TSocket tSocket = new TSocket("xxxx", xxxx);
                    TTransport trans = new TFramedTransport(tSocket);)
            {
                System.out.println("Port: " + tSocket.getSocket().getLocalPort());
                TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(trans);
                TMultiplexedProtocol tmp = new TMultiplexedProtocol(protocol, xxxx.class.getSimpleName());
                xxx.Client client = new xxx.Client(tmp);
                trans.open();
                String targetPath = client.xxx("ls -al xxx");
                System.out.println(targetPath + "--" + (count++));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I started two clients running the above client code

Comment: Slightly off topic, but what you are creating looks like a perfect [**backdoor to execute arbitrary commands on a server**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backdoor_(computing)). Sure that is the right thing to do?

Comment: @JensG,  Sorry, the sample code is slightly incorrect. The server side executes fixed code, not arbitrary code. The parameter passed by the client is actually a path, not an arbitrary linux command. The above client sample code is slightly incorrect, just to show that the server side executes 'ls -al'.